# How do I make a function run again if, and only if, it returns null in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, use-effect, use-state

I have a RN/Expo project that, at times, returns a null value because the data just hasn't had the time to load.

The data is coming from an AWS server.

If I refresh the page, this will normally fix itself, however this is not a long term solution.

How can I modify this function so that it will run again, if, and only if, it returns a "null" response for any of the variables?

Below is my code:

```
const [ firstName, getFirstName ] = useState('')
const [ phone, getPhone ] = useState('')
const [ email, getEmail ] = useState('')
const [ userPhoto, getUserPhoto ] = useState(null)

    useEffect(()=>{ 
const info_response = server_grab.get_user_info().then(response=>{

const displayName = async()=>{
                getFirstName(
                    <Text style = {styles.title}> 
                    {response.first_name} {response.last_name}
                    </Text>
                )
            
                getPhone(
                    <Text style = {styles.box_text}> 
                    {response.phone}
                    </Text>
                )

                getEmail(
                    <Text style = {styles.box_text}> 
                    {response.email}
                    </Text>
                )  
           
           }
          )
        }

        const displayPhoto = async () =>{
            const photo_response = server_grab.download_profile_photo().then(response=>{
                    getUserPhoto(response.photo_data.raw_data)                  
                }
            )
        }

        displayPhoto()
        displayName()
```

...

```
    return(
        <View>
            {userPhoto && <Avatar.Image source= {{uri:`data:image/jpg;base64,${userPhoto}`}}/>}
       </View>
<View>
    <Text>{firstName}</Text>
    <Text>{email}</Text>
    <Text>{phone}</Text>
</View>

)
```

Comment: which function ?

Comment: @anthony_718 I'd like this for both displayName and displayPhoto, as it sometimes happens to one or both of them

Comment: I don't understand. In general, components that have async render dependencies should be able to gracefully handle the render before the data is ready. Why do you want/need too run a function again instead of just waiting for the data?

Comment: @DaveNewton So basically, 1 of 3 things will happen.


1. All of the data will load into the screen with no issue


2. The function will be called before the data reaches the component, causing a warning, and the data won't populate

3. The data just doesn't come through.

This is normally corrected by doing a "ctrl+s" once or twice, then the user data renders.

I wanted to write something that will run the useEffect again, or parts of it, when it returns a "null"

Comment: I don’t think you’re thinking about this in the typical React/async way. The standard approach would be to grab the user info and when it’s received, set the corresponding state properties (although that seems unnecessary; can just keep the entire response and deconstruct). That’s all you need to do unless you want to handle pre-data rendering in a different way, which can be handled via conditional rendering or a wrapper around `<Text>` or whatever.

Comment: Making `displayName` async makes no sense, there’s nothing async in it. Neither it nor `displayPhoto` return anything so they’re no-ops. They’re also local to the async `get_user_info` function so can’t be used anywhere else anyway.

Comment: I agree with Dave. This could be done in a simple way, just make api calls, and set states with the results and then pass them to a proper component.

Comment: @StepanNikulenko Would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: @DaveNewton So eliminated the async portion from the functions?

Comment: More than that. And rename them; they’re setters, not getters. It might be worth the time to take a step back—I obviously don’t know for sure, but my impression is there’s some confusion around async programming in general, and how/when to handle async resolution.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of the concept you could use:

```
import { Text, View, Image, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

const simulateApiCall = (type, timeout = 1000 ) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    switch(type){
      case "firstName": 
        resolve('John');
        break;
      case 'lastName':
        resolve('Doe');
        break;
      case 'avatar':
        resolve('https://cdn1.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/31/95/user-sign-icon-person-symbol-human-avatar-vector-12693195.jpg');
        break;
    }
  }, timeout);
});

const Home = () => {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
  const [userAvatar, setUserAvatar] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadUserData();
  }, [loadUserData]);

  const loadUserData = useCallback(async () => {

    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      const userFirstName = await simulateApiCall('firstName');
      const userLastName = await simulateApiCall('lastName');

      setFirstName(userFirstName ?? '');
      setLastName(userLastName ?? '');

      setIsLoading(false);

      loadUserAvatar();

    } catch (error) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      console.log('Error loading user data');
    }
  }, [loadUserAvatar]);

  const loadUserAvatar = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const userAvatar = await simulateApiCall('avatar', 2000);
      setUserAvatar(userAvatar);
    } catch(error){
      console.log('Error loading user avatar')
    }
  }, []);

  return(<View>
     {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator /> :
        <>
          {userAvatar  && <Text>{userAvatar}</Text>}
          <Text>{firstName}</Text>
          <Text>{lastName}</Text>
        </>
     }
  </View>);
}

export default Home;
```

You can play around here https://snack.expo.dev/@steppannws/d39758